# Regex count number of replacements

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace, count

VB2012: Using regex to replace certain phrases. Is there a way to report how many replacements were actually made.

```
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^PENALTY", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
    Dim replacement As String = "PENALTY PER MINUTE"
    Dim result As String = regex.Replace(input, replacement)

    Dim p as Integer = 0 'how do I get this???
    MsgBox(p.ToString &  " replacements were made")
```

Comment: The C# code is a bit different, but the idea if really the same: use a MatchEvaluator.

Comment: ok thanks i thought there was a property I could tap into. will look at MatchEvaluator.

Comment: No, no special property is there.